# Cant get react-images to display image

Tags: reactjs

I'm having difficulties trying to render the image from Lightbox. I want to be able to click on an image, then lightbox opens up to display the same image. As of right now, the image works fine inside Lightbox, but on the dom there is no image to click on to open lightbox. I tried to copy the example from the github, but I can't figure out how to display the image that I put into the Lightbox: https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7N250S3JicmxxNmM. If someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong and guide me onto the right path I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is what I'm trying to follow: https://github.com/jossmac/react-images#quick-start

```
 class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          lightboxIsOpen: true,
          currentImage: 0,
        }
        this.closeLightbox = this.closeLightbox.bind(this);
        this.gotoNext = this.gotoNext.bind(this);
        this.gotoPrevious = this.gotoPrevious.bind(this);
        this.gotoImage = this.gotoImage.bind(this);
        this.handleClickImage = this.handleClickImage.bind(this);
        this.openLightbox = this.openLightbox.bind(this);
      }
      openLightbox (index, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          currentImage: index,
          lightboxIsOpen: true,
        });
      }
      gotoPrevious() {
          this.setState({
          currentImage: this.state.currentImage - 1,
        });
      }
      gotoNext() {
        this.setState({
          currentImage: this.state.currentImage + 1,
        });
      }
      gotoImage (index) {
        this.setState({
          currentImage: index,
        })
      }
      handleClickImage () {
        if (this.state.currentImage === this.props.images.length - 1) return;

        this.gotoNext();
      }
      closeLightbox() {
          this.setState({
          currentImage: 0,
          lightboxIsOpen: false,
        });
      }

    renderGallery () {
        const { images } = this.props;

        if (!images) return;

        const gallery = images.filter(i => i.useForDemo).map((obj, i) => {
          return (
            <a
              href={obj.src}
              className={css(classes.thumbnail, classes[obj.orientation])}
              key={i}
              onClick={(e) => this.openLightbox(i, e)}
            >
              <img src={obj.thumbnail} className={css(classes.source)} />
            </a>
          );
        });

        return (
          <div className={css(classes.gallery)}>
            {gallery}
          </div>
        );
      }


      render() {
        return (
            <div className="section">
            {this.props.heading && <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>}
            {this.props.subheading && <p>{this.props.subheading}</p>}
            {this.renderGallery()}
               <Lightbox
                currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
                images={[{ src: 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7N250S3JicmxxNmM' }]}
                isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
                onClickImage={this.handleClickImage}
                onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
                onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
                onClose={this.closeLightbox}
                onClickThumbnail={this.gotoImage}
                showThumbnails={this.props.showThumbnails}
                theme={this.props.theme}

              />

          </div>
        )
      }
    }


    ReactDOM.render(
            <App/>,document.getElementById("contents")
            )
```